# rails, inserting into hash then counting occurrences logic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, hash

i need to create a hash/array where 2 elements are stored: the country code, and the number of times the country occurred.

I want to vet some conceptual logic: i want to create a helper method that passes in a list of countries. Then, I loop through each country and will merge the country code into the hash through a series of if statements:

```
@map_country = Hash.new
if country == "United States" 
    @map_country.merge(:us => ??)
```

I'm not quite sure how I can add a counter to push into the hash. Can anyone help? Basically, I want to achieve how many times "United States" shows up.

Also, once I have this Hash completed - I want to do something different to each country based on the count. How do I go about picking out the value from the key? Moreover, how do I get just the key?

```
<% if @map_country[:country] > 5 %>
... do this with @map_country...
```

Thanks! Apologies if this is confusing, but really could use some help here. Thanks!

Comment: did my answer help here @gitastic?

Answer (score 0):

To me it sounds like you're trying to count occurrences which you can do with the `#inject` method:

```
[1] pry(main)> countries = ["United States", "Canada", "United States", "Mexico"]
=> ["United States", "Canada", "United States", "Mexico"]
[2] pry(main)> countries.inject({}) { |hash, ctr| hash[ctr] = hash[ctr].to_i + 1; hash }
=> {"United States"=>2, "Canada"=>1, "Mexico"=>1}
```

Then say you want to do something with that hash, you could loop through it like this:

```
[3] pry(main)> occ = countries.inject({}) { |hash, ctr| hash[ctr] = hash[ctr].to_i + 1; hash }
=> {"United States"=>2, "Canada"=>1, "Mexico"=>1}
[4] pry(main)> occ.each do |country, val|
[4] pry(main)*   if val == 2
[4] pry(main)*     puts "There are two occurences of #{country}"
[4] pry(main)*   end
[4] pry(main)* end
There are two occurences of United States
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're set on using a Hash (rather than a custom class) for this then just use a [`default_proc`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html#method-i-default_proc-3D) to auto-vivify entries with zeros and you a simple increment is all you need:

```
@map_country = Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = 0 }
if country == 'United States'
  @map_country[:us] += 1
```